Regex to replace specific word/phrase in delimited list
I'm trying to get Java regex working to replace specific phrases in a comma-delimited list. It should also match/replace the leading comma, and any leading/trailing whitespace. I have to use strictly Java-based regex for this solution.
For example, I have a string of BIG BOAT     , GREEN CAR,BIG BOAT, YELLOW TRUCK, BIG BOAT, AMAZON ECHO,      BIG BOAT    , BLUE CAR , BIG BOAT BLUE, TABLE, GLASSES, BIG BOAT and I have the regex of
(?:^|,\s*)BIG BOAT(?:$|[^,]*)

This seems to work in most cases. It matches all exact instances of BIG BOAT but incorrectly matches BIG BOAT BLUE.

Are double quotes part of the source string or not?

They are not, I'll edit the question

If that's the case then your regex doesn't need double quotes. I'm amazed your regex matched anything at all.

I'm not 100% what you mean, but if you are trying to match commas and whitespaces, this should work: (?:^|,\s*)BIG(?:\s{1,})BOAT(?:\s{1,},|$)

a comma delimited list. Much easier to do for that comma-delimited-list ('cdl') cdl = Arrays.stream(cdl.split("\\s*,\\s*")).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

Your initial regex was close to what you were trying to achieve. I just changed the end part (?:$|[^,]*) with \s*(?=,|$). Basically in the end bit, you want to match every BIG BOAT followed by zero or more white spaces, and then check if they're followed by a comma or be at the end of the string.
Like so, your regex matches:

an eventual leading comma
zero or more white spaces
BIG BOAT
zero or more white spaces

Here is the regex:
(?:^|,\s*)BIG BOAT\s*(?=,|$)

Here is a link to the regex at regex101
